# why is this string swap function in C not swap the strings?

Tags: c, string, function, pointers, swap

I tried to swap strings using pointers but I do not know why is this not swapping the strings?

so can anyone explain me why is it happening and also correct it?

```
#include<stdio.h> 
void swap(char *str1, char *str2) 
{ 
  char *temp = str1; 
  str1 = str2; 
  str2 = temp; 
}   
   
int main() 
{ 
  char *str1 = "geeks"; 
  char *str2 = "forgeeks"; 
  swap(str1, str2); 
  printf("str1 is %s, str2 is %s", str1, str2); 
  getchar(); 
  return 0; 
}
```

output:

```
str1 is geeks, str2 is forgeeks
```

Comment: Maybe read the second part of [the article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/swap-strings-in-c/)?

Comment: You're passing the string pointers by value into the swap function, so the swap there doesn't affect your str1 and str2 variables back in main().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're passing the pointers by value so their copies are modified, not the original `str1` and `str2`.

You could modify the signature of `swap` to pass a pointer to a pointer, then modfying its value by dereferencing it:

```
void swap(char** str1, char** str2) 
{ 
  char* temp = *str1; 
  *str1 = *str2; 
  *str2 = temp; 
}
```

And

```
char* str1 = "geeks"; 
char* str2 = "forgeeks"; 
swap(&str1, &str2);
```

Comment: thanks but str1 and str2 are addresses when passed into  swap function ,than why is it call by value , I am new to the programming please help and explain me?